# Facing error -> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: next.js

I am trying to populate `react-bootstrap-typeahead` component with API response data.Code for fetching data:

```
const getData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `${API_URL}/api/cprops?filters[propertyType]=${selectedOption?.value}` 
    );
    setMyData(response)  };
```

This method is called after dropdown option is selected. Code :

```
 const handleDropdownChange = (selectedOption) => {
    setSelectedOption(selectedOption);
    getData();
  };
```

The options paramter:

```
 options = [
 myData.data.map((item) => {
   {(item.attributes.city)}
      
     })
   ]
```

The component:

```
               <Typeahead
             
                onChange={(selected) => {
                  setSelectedLoc(selected)
                }}
               options = {options}
                placeholder="City"
              />
```

The above code snippets show my attempt. Please guide me with a solution. Thanks!